# Retrieve shareable account links from LinkedIn and Instragram in React Native CLI

Tags: react-native, instagram, linkedin-api, socialshare

I’m developing a networking app in React Native CLI for an upcoming conference event.

One of the things my client wants to include is the possibility to share your LinkedIn and Instagram account.

I would like to add two buttons during the unboarding process:

- Connect LinkedIn
- Connect Instagram

Upon clicking, it should go to the app if available, otherwise open a login web page. After connecting, the app should receive the username, avatar and shareable link.

What are the possibilities to implement this feature? Using their SSO seems overly complex just for link sharing. An alternative might be allowing users to manually paste their profile links, though this approach seems less user-friendly. Given the app’s temporary nature and our limited budget and development time, I’m seeking a balance between user experience and implementation simplicity.